# Como requerir o importar archivos JS y compilar correctamente por webpack.mix.js

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

Estoy tratando de construir un proyecto con Laravel basándome, entre otras cosas, en la aplicación de una plantilla de Bootstrap como parte gráfica de la página de inicio del sitio web.

A tal efecto, estoy tratando de realizar los pasos pertinentes para compilar toda la parte de CSS y JS a los archivos compilados de destino "public/css/app.css" y "public/js/app.js" por medio de "webpck.mix.js" gracias a Laravel Mix.

La parte de la configuración de CSS creo que lo tengo solucionado. Pero es la parte de JS que no llego a solucionarla del todo.

La plantilla es ésta: [**Start Bootstrap - Agency**](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency)
y así es cómo se ve: [**previo de la plantilla**](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/)

Cuando se navega por esta landing page, se observan ciertas funcionalidades visuales como son:

- la barra de navegación, que está fija en la parte superior de la ventana, se contrae y coge un fondo negro. Vuelve a su estado inicial cuando se vuelve a la parte superior de la página.
- cuando se pulsa en alguno de los enlaces de la barra de navegación, por medio de una animación de movimiento estilo jQuery-easing, se llega a la sección demandada.
- ventanas modales al pulsar en imágenes del portfolio.
- en el formulario de contacto, existe una validación de campos requeridos por medio de jQuery y Bootstrap que muestra mensajes de error debajo de los inputs que hayan causado error.

Vale, volviendo al proceso en Laravel:

- he creado el proyecto de Laravel y ejecutado el comando "npm install" para disponer de todas las dependencias definidas en el "package.json" que viene con el proyecto de Laravel. Entre otras cosas, tras el "npm install" ya se dispondría de jQuery, Bootstrap y, por supuesto, de Laravel Mix.
- he renombrado la vista por defecto de "welcome.blade.php" a "index.blade.php" y adaptado la ruta de "/" a esta vista.
- tal como se indica en el [GitHub](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency) de la plantilla, por NPM, he instalado dicha plantilla en el proyecto:

  - npm i startbootstrap-agency
- he sustituido el contenido del "index.blade.php" por el del "index.html" de la plantilla instalada.

  - el contenido trae, por un lado, varios Links a hojas de estilo de forma local o por CDN, y por otro, varios Scripts a archivos locales JS contenidos en carpetas de la plantilla.
  - como ya he dicho, la parte de requerir o importar los CSS la tengo solucionada al pasar los IMPORTS dentro del archivo "resources/sass/app.scss". Es la parte referida al requerimiento de los archivos JS lo que quiero pedir consejo.

Como es típico en muchas webs, al final del BODY, se requieren 6 archivos JS tal que así:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Contact form JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
<script src="js/agency.min.js"></script>
```

He sustituido todo este bloque por un solo SCRIPT que llama al archivo compilado final de "public/js/app.js":

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Como ya se ha visto, la vista requiere de jQuery, Bootstrap, jquery-easing (para las animaciones), jqBootstrapValidation (que sirve para validar el formulario de contacto), contact_me.js (para enviar el formulario), y agency.min.js (con el código JS propio de la plantilla en la que se incluye la comentada funcionalidad referida a la barra de navegación).

Entonces, en el archivo "resources/js/bootstrap.js", por defecto, ya se requiere de forma predeterminada, si no me equivoco, la parte JS de jQuery y Bootstrap con esto:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Así que supongo que no tengo que hacer más para disponer de estos dos complementos.

Por lo que se refiere al "jquery-easing", según pone en el [**NPM**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.easing), hay que instalarlo y requerirlo pasando una referencia de jQuery. Por lo que hago esto:

```
npm i jquery.easing
```

y dentro de "resources/js/bootstrap.js":

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    //Otro(s) archivo(s) a requerir
    require('jquery.easing')(window.jQuery);
} catch (e) {}
```

Para los otros 3 archivos JS que dependen de jQuery para funcionar, de primeras, hago un require hacia cada uno de ellos apuntando a la carpeta de la plantilla que está dentro de "node_modules". Tal y como se refleja en el "package.json", el nombre de la carpeta de la plantilla es "startbootstrap-agency".
Con todo ello, el bloque de "resources/js/bootstrap.js" queda de esta forma:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    //Otro(s) archivo(s) a requerir
    require('jquery.easing')(window.jQuery);
    require('startbootstrap-agency/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js');
    require('startbootstrap-agency/js/contact_me.js');
    require('startbootstrap-agency/js/agency.min.js');
} catch (e) {}
```

Como se puede ver, hago los "require" en el mismo orden en el que se hacen las llamadas a los SCRIPTS originalmente en el "index.html" de la plantilla.

En primera instancia, el contenido del "webpack.mix.js" lo dejo como viene tal que así:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

A partir de aquí, he ejecutado la compilación de archivos por Laravel Mix:

```
npm run dev
```

El comando no da error alguno. Y cuando accedo a la página por el navegador, de primeras el aspecto visual es correcto pero lo que no marcha es toda esa funcionalidad que ya he explicado y que da la parte de JS.

No funciona ni el efecto de la barra de navegación, ni los previos de ventanas modales de las imágenes, ni la validación del formulario.
Es como si el jQuery o el Bootstrap no terminara de estar accesible.

He probado otras formas de requerir los mismos archivos JS, e incluso, he hecho una copia de los JS locales de la plantilla y los he puesto dentro de una nueva carpeta "libs" dentro de "resources/js" y dejando el bloque de "resources/js/bootstrap.js" así:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    //Otro(s) archivo(s) a requerir
    require('jquery.easing')(window.jQuery);
    require('./libs/jqBootstrapValidation.js');
    require('./libs/contact_me.js');
    require('./libs/agency.js');
} catch (e) {}
```

y tras volver a compilar, sigue sin aplicarse la funcionalidad de jQuery.

De la única forma que todo me funciona, aparte de dejar la manera de llamada original a cada uno de los SCRIPTS, es realizando los require dentro del propio "webpack.mix.js", incluso de los archivos referidos a jQuery, Bootstrap y jQuery-easing, tal que así:

```
mix.scripts([
        'resources/js/libs/jquery.js',
        'resources/js/libs/bootstrap.min.js',
        'resources/js/libs/jquery.easing.js',
        'resources/js/libs/jqBootstrapValidation.js',
        'resources/js/libs/contact_me.js',
        'resources/js/libs/agency.js',
        'resources/js/app.js',
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Como digo, así las funcionalidades si marchan. Lo que me salen, entonces, son errores en la consola del navegador que me comunican:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at app.js:11612
```

La línea a la que se refiere este error es a esta línea de la parte del "resources/js/app.js"

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

Y si comento esta línea, en la siguiente actualización de la página, en la consola del navegador, el mismo error se refiere, entonces, a la siguiente línea del mismo archivo "resources/js/app.js":

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

Los dos errores son referidos al "require" como si ya no los reconociera. Y supongo que cuando añada la funcionalidad de Vue, debido a este error, no llegue a funcionar.

Así que, por un lado, cuando hago los "require" en el archivo "resources/js/bootstrap.js", parece como si el jQuery no fuera accedido por los otros 3 archivos que lo requieren para funcionar (hablo, al menos, de los de la validación de formulario y la funcionalidad de la barra de navegación).
Por otro lado, llego que la funcionalidad funcione pero, entonces, se detecta un error de que no reconoce los "require" de ciertos componentes necesarios.

Por tanto, ¿que es lo que hago mal a la hora de hacer los "require" en el bloque de "resources/js/bootstrap.js"? ¿no es la forma correcta de requerir los archivos necesarios?, ¿deberían ser IMPORT en vez de REQUIRE?

¿El orden en que se hacen los require es tal y como son construidos en el "public/js/app.js" final? ¿el webpack.min.js respete este orden?
¿Acaso, por alguna razón, el jQuery se me carga después de los archivos que lo requieren y por eso no funcionan?

Y si tengo que hacer las refencias a compilar dentro del propio "webpack.mix.js" es que la forma en la que las funcionalidades marchan, ¿cómo resuelvo el error de que no reconozca los demás "require"?

Espero vuestras sugerencias. Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Actualmente poseo el mismo problema, solo toma el primer require, lo pudiste solucionar?

Comment: Hola Matías. No solucioné tal y como demandaba en mi pregunta sino que hice una especie de mezcla. En el bootstrap.js. dejé los require de Bootstrap y JqueryEasing y los REQUIRE de mis otros JS contenidos en mi carpeta LIBS, los quité. Respecto a esos 3 JS, en el webpack, puse un comando que copia el contenido de esa carpeta en el directorio de PUBLIC que se indique, quedándome así mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').copyDirectory('resources/js/libs', 'public/js'). En el archivo que lo necesite, llamo al APP.JS y a cada uno de los otros JS.